# the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, xcode7

"The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x15db0e70, and it is attached to UICollectionView: 0x161ad800

frame = (0 120; 320 399)

clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}

contentSize: {375, 50}> collection view layout: ."

The crazy part is : 
 - This is a storyboard only collectionview (tried to get rid of the issue so i deleted the collectionview on it, so this one is brand new, just embed in a navigation controller, no size or anything was touch).
 - This collectionview is not related to a controller whatsoever (like i said, trying to get rid of the error... so i don't load my controller and i still get this.

My testing device is an iphone 5c, the problem might be that xcode wants to apply whathever he wants to apply to an iphone 6, but the autolayout is activate by default on the collectionview, i don't get it...

Comment: What does your sizeForItemAtIndexPath method look like? What size are your collection view cells? At first glance it seems your collection cells may be wider (375) than the collection view (320).

Comment: You didn't read me, the collectionview on the storyboard is brand new, and i don't have ANY code related to it, nothing, so no method and no size define for the cells.
Xcode in someway put a default iphone6 size on this collectionview but i have no idea why as i use auto layout

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so basically if anywhere in your entire project you specify a 4.7 inch size for a view on one of your storyboards, xcode will put the iphone 6 native size by default and it will mess up with your collectionview if your device is another type of iphone...